# Android BottomNavigation showes "Up Button" when navigating between tabs

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I've sat up a bottom navigation bar in my app. When I enable action bar with `navController`, the up button shows when navigating between tabs.

[Fig.1: up button is gone when I'm in home destination]

[image]

---

[Fig.2: up button show up when navigation between tabs]

[image]

It goes away when i remove this line in `MainActivity` but then I lose up button for the whole app:

```
setUpActionBarWithNavCotroller(navController)
```

How can i make "Up Button" disapper from bottom navigation tabs?

Comment: Please add your (relevant) codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Tasks` and `Categories` are `top-level` destinations. So, you have to assign them to navController. Here's the official [documentation.](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#create_a_toolbar)

##### Step 1:

Initialize `AppBarConfiguration` as follow

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        topLevelDestinationIds = setOf(R.id.tasksFragment, R.id.categoriesFragment)
    )
```

##### Step 2:

Assign them to navController with your `Toolbar`

```
findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        .setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

**or** `ActionBar`

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of furthur search and I found out that it's actualy possible to set **multiple** Top-level destinations manually so "Up Button" wouldn't be showed in them. Using `AppBarConfiguration` to add those destinations.

### `MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        // Adding multiple top-level destinations using AppBarConfigutaion
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.categoriesFragment, R.id.tasksFragment))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```